# Containers in a multiple container openshift pod can't communicate between themselves

Tags: openshift, spring-cloud-config, minishift

I'm working on migrating our existing docker containers into openshift, and am running into an issue trying to get 2 of our containers into a single pod. We're using Spring Cloud Config Server for our services, with a Gitea backend. I'd like to have these in a single pod so that the java server and git server are always tied together.

I'm able to get to each of the containers individually via the associated routes, but the config server is unable to reach the git server, and vice versa. I get a 404 when the config server tries to clone the git repo. I've tried using gitea-${INSTANCE_IDENTIFIER} (INSTANCE_IDENTIFIER just being a generated value to tie all of the objects together at a glance), gitea-${INSTANCE_IDENTIFIER}.myproject.svc, and gitea-${INSTANCE_IDENTIFIER}.myproject.svc.cluster.local, as well as the full url for the route that gets created, and nothing works.

Here is my template, with a few things removed (...) for security:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Template
metadata:
  name: configuration-template
  annotations:
    description: 'Configuration containers template'
    iconClass: 'fa fa-gear'
    tags: 'git, Spring Cloud Configuration'
objects:
  - apiVersion: v1
    kind: ConfigMap
    metadata:
      name: 'gitea-config-${INSTANCE_IDENTIFIER}'
      labels:
        app: 'configuration-${INSTANCE_IDENTIFIER}'
        gitea: '${GITEA_VERSION}'
        configuration: '${CONFIGURATION_VERSION}'
    data:
      local-docker.ini: |
        APP_NAME = Git Server
        RUN_USER = git
        RUN_MODE = prod

        [repository]
        ROOT = /home/git/data/git/repositories

        [repository.upload]
        TEMP_PATH = /home/git/data/gitea/uploads

        [server]
        APP_DATA_PATH    = /home/git/data/gitea
        HTTP_PORT        = 8443
        DISABLE_SSH      = true
        SSH_PORT         = 22
        LFS_START_SERVER = false
        OFFLINE_MODE     = false
        PROTOCOL     = https
        CERT_FILE    = /var/run/secrets/service-cert/tls.crt
        KEY_FILE     = /var/run/secrets/service-cert/tls.key
        REDIRECT_OTHER_PORT = true
        PORT_TO_REDIRECT = 8080

        [database]
        PATH     = /home/git/data/gitea/gitea.db
        DB_TYPE  = sqlite3
        NAME     = gitea
        USER     = gitea
        PASSWD   = XXXX

        [session]
        PROVIDER_CONFIG = /home/git/data/gitea/sessions
        PROVIDER        = file

        [picture]
        AVATAR_UPLOAD_PATH      = /home/git/data/gitea/avatars
        DISABLE_GRAVATAR        = false
        ENABLE_FEDERATED_AVATAR = false

        [attachment]
        PATH = /home/git/data/gitea/attachments

        [log]
        ROOT_PATH = /home/git/data/gitea/log
        MODE      = file
        LEVEL     = Info

        [mailer]
        ENABLED = false

        [service]
        REGISTER_EMAIL_CONFIRM     = false
        ENABLE_NOTIFY_MAIL         = false
        DISABLE_REGISTRATION       = false
        ENABLE_CAPTCHA             = false
        REQUIRE_SIGNIN_VIEW        = false
        DEFAULT_KEEP_EMAIL_PRIVATE = false
        NO_REPLY_ADDRESS           = noreply.example.org

  - apiVersion: v1
    kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
    metadata:
      name: 'gitea-${INSTANCE_IDENTIFIER}'
      labels:
        app: 'configuration-${INSTANCE_IDENTIFIER}'
        gitea: '${GITEA_VERSION}'
        configuration: '${CONFIGURATION_VERSION}'
    spec:
      accessModes:
        - ReadWriteOnce
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 1Gi
  - apiVersion: v1
    kind: Route
    metadata:
      name: 'gitea-${INSTANCE_IDENTIFIER}'
      labels:
        app: 'configuration-${INSTANCE_IDENTIFIER}'
        gitea: '${GITEA_VERSION}'
        configuration: '${CONFIGURATION_VERSION}'
    spec:
      port:
        targetPort: 'https'
      tls:
        termination: 'passthrough'
      to:
        kind: Service
        name: 'gitea-${INSTANCE_IDENTIFIER}'
  - apiVersion: v1
    kind: Service
    metadata:
      name: 'gitea-${INSTANCE_IDENTIFIER}'
      labels:
        app: 'configuration-${INSTANCE_IDENTIFIER}'
        gitea: '${GITEA_VERSION}'
        configuration: '${CONFIGURATION_VERSION}'
      annotations:
        service.alpha.openshift.io/serving-cert-secret-name: 'gitea-certs-${INSTANCE_IDENTIFIER}'
    spec:
      type: ClusterIP
      ports:
        - name: 'https'
          port: 443
          targetPort: 8443
      selector:
        app: 'configuration-${INSTANCE_IDENTIFIER}'
  - apiVersion: v1
    kind: Route
    metadata:
      name: 'configuration-${INSTANCE_IDENTIFIER}'
      labels:
        app: 'configuration-${INSTANCE_IDENTIFIER}'
        gitea: '${GITEA_VERSION}'
        configuration: '${CONFIGURATION_VERSION}'
    spec:
      port:
        targetPort: 'https'
      tls:
        termination: 'passthrough'
      to:
        kind: Service
        name: 'configuration-${INSTANCE_IDENTIFIER}'
  - apiVersion: v1
    kind: Service
    metadata:
      name: 'configuration-${INSTANCE_IDENTIFIER}'
      labels:
        app: 'configuration-${INSTANCE_IDENTIFIER}'
        gitea: '${GITEA_VERSION}'
        configuration: '${CONFIGURATION_VERSION}'
      annotations:
        service.alpha.openshift.io/serving-cert-secret-name: 'configuration-certs-${INSTANCE_IDENTIFIER}'
    spec:
      type: ClusterIP
      ports:
        - name: 'https'
          port: 443
          targetPort: 8105
      selector:
        app: 'configuration-${INSTANCE_IDENTIFIER}'
  - apiVersion: v1
    kind: DeploymentConfig
    metadata:
      name: 'gitea-${INSTANCE_IDENTIFIER}'
      labels:
        app: 'configuration-${INSTANCE_IDENTIFIER}'
        gitea: '${GITEA_VERSION}'
        configuration: '${CONFIGURATION_VERSION}'
    spec:
      selector:
        app: 'configuration-${INSTANCE_IDENTIFIER}'
      replicas: 1
      template:
        metadata:
          labels:
            app: 'configuration-${INSTANCE_IDENTIFIER}'
            gitea: '${GITEA_VERSION}'
        spec:
          initContainers:
            - name: pem-to-keystore
              image: nginx
              env:
                - name: keyfile
                  value: /var/run/secrets/openshift.io/services_serving_certs/tls.key
                - name: crtfile
                  value: /var/run/secrets/openshift.io/services_serving_certs/tls.crt
                - name: keystore_pkcs12
                  value: /var/run/secrets/java.io/keystores/keystore.pkcs12
                - name: password
                  value: '${STORE_PASSWORD}'
              command: ['sh']
              args: ['-c', "openssl pkcs12 -export -inkey $keyfile -in $crtfile -out $keystore_pkcs12 -password pass:$password -name 'server certificate'"]
              volumeMounts:
                - mountPath: /var/run/secrets/java.io/keystores
                  name: 'configuration-keystore-${INSTANCE_IDENTIFIER}'
                - mountPath: /var/run/secrets/openshift.io/services_serving_certs
                  name: 'configuration-certs-${INSTANCE_IDENTIFIER}'
            - name: pem-to-truststore
              image: openjdk:alpine
              env:
                - name: ca_bundle
                  value: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/service-ca.crt
                - name: truststore_jks
                  value: /var/run/secrets/java.io/keystores/truststore.jks
                - name: password
                  value: '${STORE_PASSWORD}'
              command: ['/bin/sh']
              args: ["-c",
                     "keytool -noprompt -importkeystore -srckeystore $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts -srcstoretype JKS -destkeystore $truststore_jks -storepass $password -srcstorepass changeit && cd /var/run/secrets/java.io/keystores/ && awk '/-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----/{filename=\"crt-\"NR}; {print >filename}' $ca_bundle && for file in crt-*; do keytool -import -noprompt -keystore $truststore_jks -file $file -storepass $password -alias service-$file; done && rm crt-*"]
              volumeMounts:
                - mountPath: /var/run/secrets/java.io/keystores
                  name: 'configuration-keystore-${INSTANCE_IDENTIFIER}'
          containers:
            - name: 'gitea-${INSTANCE_IDENTIFIER}'
              image: '...'
              command: ['sh',
                        '-c',
                        'tar xf /app/gitea/gitea-data.tar.gz -C /home/git/data && cp /app/config/local-docker.ini /home/git/config/local-docker.ini && gitea web --config /home/git/config/local-docker.ini']
              ports:
                - containerPort: 8443
                  protocol: TCP
              imagePullPolicy: Always
              volumeMounts:
                - mountPath: '/home/git/data'
                  name: 'gitea-data-${INSTANCE_IDENTIFIER}'
                  readOnly: false
                - mountPath: '/app/config'
                  name: 'gitea-config-${INSTANCE_IDENTIFIER}'
                  readOnly: false
                - mountPath: '/var/run/secrets/service-cert'
                  name: 'gitea-certs-${INSTANCE_IDENTIFIER}'
            - name: 'configuration-${INSTANCE_IDENTIFIER}'
              image: '...'
              env:
                - name: POD_NAME
                  valueFrom:
                    fieldRef:
                      fieldPath: metadata.name
                - name: POD_NAMESPACE
                  valueFrom:
                    fieldRef:
                      fieldPath: metadata.namespace
              command: [
                "java",
                "-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom",
                "-Dspring.profiles.active=terraform",
                "-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/var/run/secrets/java.io/keystores/truststore.jks",
                "-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStoreType=JKS",
                "-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=${STORE_PASSWORD}",
                "-Dserver.ssl.key-store=/var/run/secrets/java.io/keystores/keystore.pkcs12",
                "-Dserver.ssl.key-store-password=${STORE_PASSWORD}",
                "-Dserver.ssl.key-store-type=PKCS12",
                "-Dserver.ssl.trust-store=/var/run/secrets/java.io/keystores/truststore.jks",
                "-Dserver.ssl.trust-store-password=${STORE_PASSWORD}",
                "-Dserver.ssl.trust-store-type=JKS",
                "-Dspring.cloud.config.server.git.uri=https://gitea-${INSTANCE_IDENTIFIER}.svc.cluster.local/org/centralrepo.git",
                "-jar",
                "/app.jar"
              ]
              ports:
                - containerPort: 8105
                  protocol: TCP
              imagePullPolicy: Always
              volumeMounts:
                - mountPath: '/var/run/secrets/java.io/keystores'
                  name: 'configuration-keystore-${INSTANCE_IDENTIFIER}'
                  readOnly: true
                - mountPath: 'target/centralrepo'
                  name: 'configuration-${INSTANCE_IDENTIFIER}'
                  readOnly: false
          volumes:
            - name: 'gitea-data-${INSTANCE_IDENTIFIER}'
              persistentVolumeClaim:
                claimName: 'gitea-${INSTANCE_IDENTIFIER}'
            - name: 'gitea-config-${INSTANCE_IDENTIFIER}'
              configMap:
                defaultMode: 0660
                name: 'gitea-config-${INSTANCE_IDENTIFIER}'
            - name: 'gitea-certs-${INSTANCE_IDENTIFIER}'
              secret:
                defaultMode: 0640
                secretName: 'gitea-certs-${INSTANCE_IDENTIFIER}'
            - name: 'configuration-keystore-${INSTANCE_IDENTIFIER}'
              emptyDir:
            - name: 'configuration-certs-${INSTANCE_IDENTIFIER}'
              secret:
                defaultMode: 0640
                secretName: 'configuration-certs-${INSTANCE_IDENTIFIER}'
            - name: 'configuration-${INSTANCE_IDENTIFIER}'
              emptyDir:
                defaultMode: 660
          restartPolicy: Always
          terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 62
          dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
    strategy:
      type: RollingUpdate
      rollingUpdate:
        maxUnavailable: 1
        maxSurge: 1
parameters:
  - name: GITEA_VERSION
    displayName: Gitea Image Version
    description: The version of the gitea image.
    required: true
  - name: CONFIGURATION_VERSION
    displayName: Configuration Service Image Version
    description: The version of the configuration service image.
    required: true
  - name: INSTANCE_IDENTIFIER
    description: Provides an identifier to tie all objects in the deployment together.
    generate: expression
    from: "[a-z0-9]{6}"
  - name: STORE_PASSWORD
    generate: expression
    from: "[a-zA-Z0-9]{25}"
```

Comment: 404 means you reached the enpoint but the requested "page" does not exist, not that you can not reach gitea...check the resource you are trying to reach

Comment: I'm able to request the resource from the web using the route, so I know that it exists and is reachable.

Comment: Agree with @titou10 -  look at the HTTP access logs of the container that's responding 404 to compare how it sees the request URL when it's coming from outside vs inside

Comment: How are you trying to hit the service? 
Also, are you sure you need both of these in the same pod?